# What is the right Bonferroni adjustment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, nonparametric, bonferroni, friedman-test

I am trying to test a hypothesis for my Masters Thesis.

There are 3 conditions (I will name them X, Y, Z), in each of which the data isn't normally distributed, and measures the improvement for each condition. I ran a Friedman test as a repeated measure, and in post-hoc I ran a Wilcoxon test with the Bonferroni adjustment.

My problem is that I want to compare only X vs Y and X vs Z (and not Y vs Z).

My question is this: for the Bonferroni correction do I need to divide by 2 or 3?

On one hand, there are 3 comparisons done in the SPSS test, but on the other I'm only interested in 2 of them.

Does this even count as a repeated measure?

Thank you!

Comment: We need more information for the "repeated measure" part of the question. Is this one group of subjects measured three times, or three different groups of subjects each measured once?

Comment: Note that "[repeated measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design)" has a technical meaning in statistics, representing multiple measurements on the same individual under different conditions or over time. I think that what you're asking about is really [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). If I'm correct, please change the tag and edit your question so that future visitors to this page won't be confused. If there is a repeated measures issue, please address the comment from @TPM.

Comment: @TPM This is one group of subjects. They each go through all 3 treatments (conditions) on different sessions, and are measured each time.

Answer (score 7):

To the best of my knowledge, the Bonferroni correction is based on the number of tests you actually perform, not on the total number of pairwise tests that you *could* perform. So if you set out to perform two pairwise comparisons, you should divide by two.

Comment: This is correct. One point to consider is that if the p-value for the YZ comparison turns out to be significant, it still shouldn't be considered significant. It should be as if you never calculated that p-value, since its calculation is just a matter of the software doing it by default (and this most likely can be changed).

Comment: Also you should make sure it is Bonferroni (or Holm) you are interested and want to control family-wise error rate (FWER) rather than BHY (Benjamini-Hochberg-Yakutieli) which controls false discovery rate (FDR).